# Regex in PHP: how do I replace hyphens between alphanumeric characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find and then replace instances of hyphens with en and em widths.

So, in the example: "10-100" the hyphen would be replaced by an en width. Also, in the example: "It is - without doubt - the worst" or: "It is -- without doubt -- the worst" either instances would be replaced by an em width.

However, I just can't figure out the proper pattern for preg_replace() in PHP.

```
"/[0-9]+(\-)[0-9]+/"
```

... appears to do the replace, but removes the numbers.

How do I get preg_replace() to ignore the patterns either side of the subject?

Comment: With [assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I suppose it goes without saying that Regular Expressions are weird, but I got it working, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookbehinds and lookaheads:

```
function prettyDashes($string) {
    static $regex = array(
        '/(?<=\d)-(?=\d)/' => '&ndash;',  // EN-dash
        '/(?<=\s)-(?=\s)/' => '&mdash;',  // EM-dash
        '/(?<=\w)--(?=\w)/' => '&mdash;', // EM-dash
    );
    return preg_replace(array_keys($regex), array_values($regex), $string);
}
$tests = array(
    'There are 10-20 dogs in the kennel.',
    'My day was - without a doubt - the worst!',
    'My day was--without a doubt--the worst!',
);
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo prettyDashes($test), '<br>';
}
```

The problem is that it is difficult to detect and avoid false-positives when replacing stuff like this. Normal hyphenated words, like "to-do", are not tangential (em-dash), and dates, like 18-12-2014, are not ranges (en-dash). You have to be quite conservative in what you replace, and you should not be surprised if something is changed erroneously.

Comment: "The problem is that it is difficult to detect and avoid false-positives when replacing stuff like this." Which is exactly the problem I'm having at present, such as detection (and ignore) within a URL, as an example.

Comment: @WayneSmallman Yeah, that is just a problem that comes with doing this. You have to know every false-positive (or at least know how to identify them somehow) in order to avoid replacing correctly used hyphens. Implementing it would also be quite nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

So, with thanks to @mario, the answers are:

```
"/(?=.*?[0-9])(\-)(?=.*?[0-9])/"

"/(?=.*?\w)( \- )(?=.*?\w)/"

"/(?=.*?\w)( \-- )(?=.*?\w)/"
```